How important is the "clustered" property of MySQL PK index?
I am importing ~50M rows into MySQL 8, InnoDB. It's on AWS RDS with GP3 storage.
The unique key of the rows is a uuid-like string.
When querying we will never care about this unique key, except when upserting new/modified rows from the primary source.
Normally the unique id would be the PK. But I have read that PK index in MySQL is special because it aims to 'cluster' the data for similar values, to enhance performance.
It seems that by using uuid-like string as PK the clustering will not help our queries.
If I was to partition the table I would do it by date range.
I could imagine defining a synthetic PK, or a composite PK, that combines the date field and uuid to get a clustering that is more likely to support the queries we actually do.
My question is this: how important is it to have a PK clustering that supports the typical queries (i.e. fetched results likely to be 'close' in the index)?
Presumably the typical case of an auto-incrementing id for PK also results in clustering that has little relation to typical queries (often no reason to select adjacent ids).
I am thinking specifically about whether modern SSD storage makes this type of optimisation less important, obsolete... or even more important?
More context
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

How the Clustered Index Speeds Up Queries
Accessing a row through the
clustered index is fast because the index search leads directly to the
page that contains the row data. If a table is large, the clustered
index architecture often saves a disk I/O operation when compared to
storage organizations that store row data using a different page from
the index record.

It seems like the "clustered"-ness of the PK index is only of value for queries which select by PK.
It's about co-locating the row data with the index (?)
So if all the application queries that I care about use secondary indexes I guess it doesn't really matter what the properties of the PK are? e.g. including a date partition column in the PK isn't going to magically speed up queries using a different index.
Is that right?

You confuse the index (which is used for queries improvement) and the constraint (which provides the data consistency). PK performs both functions, and, of course, at least one of them is performed with non-optimal way. We cannot deprive the index function from PK, but we can deprive the constraint function. So fake PK with (secondary index + CHECK) which provides according constraints may be reasonable.

or a composite PK, that combines the date field and uuid There is a problem. The date column cannot be autoutilized/generated one in this case, and you must set its value explicitly in the query or in the BEFORE trigger.

@Akina For this use case I don't care about the unique constraint that PK provides, the data is already validated in another db. I do not need to generate any pk ids in my db, they will come from external data. My question is about trying to understand the properties of "clustered" index, which according to docs in MySQL is special about PK index compared to secondary indexes.

I don't care about the unique constraint that PK provides Well, do not create according CHECK constraints and unique indices simply.

@Akina my question is about the "clustered" property of the PK index as described here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html "Accessing a row through the clustered index is fast because the index search leads directly to the page that contains the row data. If a table is large, the clustered index architecture often saves a disk I/O operation when compared to storage organizations that store row data using a different page from the index record." ...I am looking for info on how important this really is or not, in AWS RDS/GP3 context.

If there exists PK in the table then it is clustered unconditionally. Your question makes no sense in this context.

@Akina I am trying to understand what clustering means, how best to make use of it, whether it is useful property to try and optimise for my use case

It depends.
For "point queries" via the PK, there is 1 BTree lookup.
For "point queries" via a secondary index, there are two BTree lookups.
For "range queries", UUIDs are virtually useless -- the rows will be scattered around.  (However, see UUIDs .)
For chronologically clustered info...  If you have, say, news articles and most requests are for "recent" articles, it would be beneficial to have the data sorted chronologically.  AUTO_INCREMENT (mostly) achieves this; UUIDs do not (again, see the above link,)
If your external providers are giving you UUIDs, and later referring to them, then do use UUIDs as PKs.  The overhead of turning the UUIDs into auto_inc ids is probably not worth it.
If the entire table fits in innodb_buffer_pool_size, then a production server will eventually get all the blocks (16KB each) will eventually be cached in RAM.  In this case, it does not matter whether the PK is auto_inc or UUID or something else.
In some rare applications (2D index useful) PARTITIONing may be useful.  (But I don't see that in the Question.)
Do pack UUIDs into BINARY(16) (see link or functions now available in MySQL and MariaDB).  (Saving space decreases I/O -- a little -- thereby helping performance.)

Thanks, I think these are basically the conclusions I had come to (largely from reading your posts elsewhere ). Our only use for the UUID is periodically upserting modified rows, otherwise we are doing aggregates over date range + filter columns.  The db is ~120GB, mostly in the two largest tables. So I have to have the PK but I think there is no value in making it composite since most of the time secondary index will be used instead.

"If you have, say, news articles and most requests are for "recent" articles, it would be beneficial to have the data sorted chronologically" does the clustered PK index actually help with this if you are not referencing the PK column in the SELECT query?

If the table is too big to stay cached in RAM, "old" blocks (with "old" news articles) will be bumped out.  Meanwhile "new" articles will tend to stay cached -- thereby decreasing I/O.  There are 3 things:  (1) bias toward fetching "new" articles; (2) PK in [roughly] chronological order, and (3) the table does not fit in RAM.

So the clustered PK index helps by storing rows which are commonly selected together in the same blocks, which helps because more likely to get disk cache hits even if query doesn't use PK index... but only if rows 'close' by their PK value are commonly selected together. So we might benefit from a composite (date, id) PK if we can guarantee that the date doesn't change. Naively this sounds like a case for partitioning by date, though I have read your advice that partitioning is often not helpful.

@Anentropic - A "block" has about 100 rows and is fetched as a unit.  A "partition" typically has millions of rows -- stored as lots of blocks.

And...  For 1000-row tables, none of this discussion matters much .  For a million-row table, most of this should be learned and applied.  For a billion-row table, even more stuff needs to be discussed.

The two biggest tables are ~40M and ~90M rows.  The "block" here is an InnoDB page?  So however many rows fit in the page size (16KB default) ?

block == page, Rule of Thumb: 100 per page.  Start a new Question with SHOW CREATE TABLE and some important queries; we can go into more details.


I am trying to understand what clustering means, how best to make use of it, whether it is useful property to try and optimise for my use case – Anentropic

What is the index in general? Wу specify some expression. This expression value is calculated for each row in our rowset. Then these values (accompanied with the reference to the row which produces the value) are sorted. Now, when we know the value of the expression, we can easily find the row(s) whose expression have needed value, using half  division method.
What is secondary and non-clustered index in InnoDB? The server calculates the index expression for each row, sorts and saves the result to the index which is separate disk structure. Now, when we specify the index expression value, the server searches for this value in the index, then gets the reference to the row itself (which is posessed in the table body file on the disk), and retrieves the row itself using this reference.
What is clustered index? The server calculates the index expression for each row, sorts the rows according this expression values and saves the rows to the disk in this order. Now, when we specify the index expression value, the server searches for this value in the index, and when it finds this index value then it also finds the row itself. We do not need to jump to the table body - we are in it already.
And again about secondary index. I have said that the index expression value in it is accompanied with the reference on the row itself. This reference should help to find the row itself as fast as possible - so this reference is clustered index expression value. I.e. when we search by secondary index then we use binary search by its expression value, take according clustered index expression value, and use binary search by this clustered expression value for to find the row itself.
Finally. When we search the row by secondary index then we need to perform 2 searches. When we search by clustered index then we need one search only.

"Search" refers to a BTree lookup, which is reasonably fast.
